# Form going to 404 page when name input has a value

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am completely stumped with this (that, or I've just been staring at it for too long that there is an obvious error and I can't see it)

I've got a simple form which validates on the same page which is a custom template I have made

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your full name" />
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address" />
  <input type="hidden" name="newsletterform" value="newsletterform" />
  <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

It is then validated like so

```
<?php
  $formsubmitted = (!empty($_POST['newsletterform'])) ? $_POST['newsletterform'] : "";
   if($formsubmitted !== ''){
    $fullname = (!empty($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
    $email = (!empty($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

    $failed = '';

    if (empty($fullname)){
        $failed.= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
    }
    if (empty($email)){
        $failed.= 'Please enter your email address.<br />';
    }
}
if ($failed == '' and $formsubmitted !== ''){ ?>
    <div id="success-title">
        Thank you for signing up!
    </div>
<?php
}
if ($failed !== '' and $formsubmitted !== '') { ?>
    <div id="error-title">
        Sorry, we could not accept the details you submitted to us. Please see below.
    </div>
    <div id="error-body">
        <?php echo $failed;?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

It shows the errors when you try to send an empty form, it validates the email fine when there is a value in there and when the name field is empty. When something is entered into the name field when there is something or nothing in the email field it goes to my 404 page.

Comment: Try to remove your empty action `action=""`, form should automatically redirect to the same page

Comment: @Fabio you're right it still uses the same page but it's still redirecting to the 404 when something is entered in the name input... So strange

Comment: are you including this script in another page?

Comment: No it's all on the same page

Comment: Is there any more code you didn't post which may cause the error?

Comment: No, I had a few Mysql stuff in there which I took out and then tried that with the same problem so the code I posted is the final more basic code I tried.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31261/discussion-between-laura-clarke-and-fabio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very simple, avoid using in forms the `name` attribute called "name".

change:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your full name" />
```

to:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="myname" placeholder="Please enter your full name" />
```

Additional info:

[Unsafe Names for HTML Form Controls](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/)

Comment: I actually love you! Such a basic thing!

Comment: But *why* is it redirecting because the `name` attribute has "name" in it?

Answer (score 0):

For me it works fine in this way, try replace your PHP with this:

```
<?php
$failed = '';

  $formsubmitted = (!empty($_POST['newsletterform'])) ? $_POST['newsletterform'] : "";
   if($formsubmitted !== ''){
    $fullname = (!empty($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
    $email = (!empty($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : "";

    if (empty($fullname)){
        $failed.= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
    }
    if (empty($email)){
        $failed.= 'Please enter your email address.<br />';
    }
}
if ($failed == '' and $formsubmitted !== ''){ 
    echo '<div id="success-title">
        Thank you for signing up!
    </div>';

}
if ($failed !== '' and $formsubmitted !== '') { 

    echo '<div id="error-title">
        Sorry, we could not accept the details you submitted to us. Please see below.
    </div>
    <div id="error-body">';
    echo $failed;
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hmmm I replaced my PHP with that and it was still going to my 404 page when I inserted something into the name input

Comment: Strange, when I test it it just shows me the error like he should do. Then it must be something with your post. What is the action and how do you redirect to the page?

Comment: The action is: action="" but i've also tried it with: action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/sign-up-to-receive-our-monthly-newsletter/" I've used this method on a seperate template I created and it works fine :s

Comment: Strange, and there isnt something different 100% sure?

Comment: 110% sure! It's driving me mad :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this --

```
<?php
if (strlen($fullname) < 3) {
            // name too short, add error
            $errors['name_error'] = 'Your name is required';
        }elseif(strlen($fullname) ==0){
         $errors['name_error'] = 'Your name is required';
        }

        if (strlen($email) == 0) {
            // no email address given
            $errors['email_error'] = 'Email address is required';
        } else if ( !preg_match('/^(?:[\w\d]+\.?)+@(?:(?:[\w\d]\-?)+\.)+\w{2,4}$/i', $email)) {
            // invalid email format
            $errors['email_error'] = 'Email address entered is invalid';
        }

    if (sizeof($errors) == 0) {
 echo '<div id="success-title">
    Thank you for signing up!
</div>';
     }
     else {
     echo 'Sorry, we could not accept the details you submitted to us. Please see below.' . $errors; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Please use `filter_var` to validate email addresses.

Comment: Still doesn't work, it's still redirecting to the 404 page when something is entered in the name field. Also I'm using type="email" on the input to validate it.

Comment: Do not do that. input type='email' is included in HTML5 and if you are using older version of PHP it won't support.

Comment: @LauraClarke `type="email"` is only client-side validation, which older *browsers* don't support. **Always** validate user input at the server side, e.g., validate email addresses using PHP's `filter_var` function.