# 404 Error with name="name" field

Tags: wordpress

After a lot of search I found some answers that a form goes to 404 page if it has a input field with name attribute set to `name` but could not find a reason why this is happening.

I am writing a plugin which allows users to build their own form, just would like to avoid any such conflict by the users of the plugin.

I have read answers form here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-submit-redirecting-to-404-page

[Form going to 404 page when name input has a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941000/form-going-to-404-page-when-name-input-has-a-value)

but they don't answer why this is happening.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is a reserved term in WordPress - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Comment: Yes, that's true but where does it conflicts with the form submission. Also I could not find how `name` being used by WordPress.

Comment: You should check core files where WordPress uses that. On your side, you should always prefix things when you are developing plugins.

Comment: @ArunSingh Did you read the link? `Avoiding the following reserved terms is particularly important if you are passing the term through the $_GET or $_POST array.` You're `$_POST`ing the form data. This returns a 404.

Comment: thanks @RRikesh & @rnevius , I will better prefix the fields `name` attribute to avoid conflicts for now.